# Only build on master branch after pull request

Tags: travis-ci

When a pull request on GitHub is completed and merged into master, [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org) will start a new build. I would like to trigger a little different testing in this scenario. **What is the right way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of environment variables you can branch on in your scripts: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

In your particular case you should check that TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST is "false" and TRAVIS_BRANCH is "master".